cJSON to modify array of objects + adding additional values per object
I am currently having issues adding additional values to an array of objects.
The iteration seems to work somehow,
but I think I have to use the cjson_arrayforeach function differently
or get rid of some loops.
This my experimental code:
 cJSON *json = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
if (json == NULL) {
const char *error_ptr = cJSON_GetErrorPtr();
if (error_ptr != NULL) {
printf("Error: %s\n", error_ptr);
}
cJSON_Delete(json);
return 1;
}

cJSON *iterate = NULL;
cJSON *iterate = NULL;
cJSON_ArrayForEach(iterate,json) {
int count = 0 ;
while(count == 0) {

        cJSON *valuea = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(iterate,"valuea");
        cJSON *valueb = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(iterate, "valueb");
        for(int a = 0; a < cJSON_GetArraySize(json);a++) {

            if(cJSON_IsNumber(valuea)&&cJSON_GetNumberValue(valueb)==58) {

                int va = valuea->valueint;
                int va1 = va >> 8;
                int va2 = va & 256;
                if(a == 0) {
                    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child,"va1",va1);
                    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child,"va2",va2);


                }
                else {
                    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child->next,"va1",va1);
                    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child->next,"va2",va2);

                }
        

            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}

JSON Original
[{"valuea":5434,"Bytes":1,"valueb": 58},
  {"valuea":61578,"Bytes":1,"valueb": 58},
  {"valuea":61258,"Bytes":2,"valueb": 56}
]

And this is what was added to my JSON file
[{ "valuea":5434, "Bytes":  1, "valueb":58, "va1":21, 
"va2":  256, "va1": 240, "va2": 0 },
 { "valuea":61578, "Bytes": 1, "valueb":58, "va1":  21, 
"va2":  256, "va1": 21,
 "va2": 256, "va1": 240, "va2": 0,
 "va1": 240, "va2": 0 }, {
"valuea":   61258, "Bytes": 2, 
"valueb":   56 }]

There should be just one line of va1 & va2 per object.
Alternative code (a bit shortened)
 cJSON_ArrayForEach(iterate, json) {
        if(cJSON_IsNumber(cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(iterate,"valuea"))&&cJSON_GetNumberValue(cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(iterate,"valueb"))==58) {

            int va = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(iterate,"valuea")->valueint;
            int va1 = va >> 8;
            int va2 = va & 256;

            cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child,"va1",va1);
            cJSON_AddNumberToObject(json->child,"va2",va2);

        }
    }

resulting in this json
[{
        "valuea":   5434,
        "Bytes":    1,
        "valueb":   58,
        "va1":  21,
        "va2":  256,
        "va1":  240,
        "va2":  0
    }, {
        "valuea":   61578,
        "Bytes":    1,
        "valueb":   58
    }, {
        "valuea":   61258,
        "Bytes":    2,
        "valueb":   56
    }]

I am trying to modify a JSON in C and want to do a calculation for each JSON object.
But the loop runs multiple times.

Two tips. 1. Add your JSON input to your post. 2. I would move the cJSON_GetArraySize() right before the for, avoiding to execute it each time.

Thanks @DiegoFerruchelli but that would only save me a bit of runtime. I added a second which doesn't write the va1/va2 values into the second object. I just don't know how to use the child / next / prev properly to make it work.

OK, now I see. The problem seems to be in the cJSON_AddNumberToObject() call. You're always writing under the first child of the original JSON object (json->child) (because the variable json doesn't change, it always point to the entire object). You should write under interate (which points to the current object, that is, to the current element of the array).

In your expected result, the pair ("va1":  21, "va2":  256) belongs to the first object (where it already is) . And ("va1":  240, "va2":  0) belongs to the second object. Nothing goes into the third object, because it doesn't have ("valueb" ==  58).

Note: when I said "it always point to the entire object" above, I was talking about the entire JSON data (in this case, the entire array, whose first child is the first one of the three objects).

It would be much easier to help you if you provide a [mre] so include the input, and test your program so you catch things like the duplicate cJSON *iterate = NULL declaration.
